# How to create regex indicating that string must have some special characters at any position?

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex in java that validates such rules:

1. one capital letter at any position
2. one of [ ._-,] at any position
3. at least one digit at any position

Can you please explain how to create such regex?

My regex with help of @CodingDuckling became like :

```
(.*[A-Z -_.,\\d].*[A-Z -_.,\\d].*[A-Z -_.,\\d].*){5,}
```

But it doesn't work for string `laVa-1234`.

I don't know how to express `at any position`. I understand that this regex is wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you grouping it and saying it has to repeat 5 or more times? Plus, be careful when putting "-" inside "[ ]", you have to escape it unless you put it at the beginning or the end of inside the brackets.

Comment: You need to use a positive lookahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be solved using positive lookahead:

```
/(?=.*[A-Z]+)(?=.*[0-9]+)(?=.*[.,_-]+).*/
```

This regex does 'lookahead' for at least one uppercase letter , at least one number and at least one of [.,_-] preceeded by anything and followed by anything.

See:
http://regex101.com/r/eN9sX4

**EDIT:**

Updated according to Boris-the-Spiders comment:

```
 /(?=.*?[A-Z]+)(?=.*?[0-9]+)(?=.*?[.,_-]+).*/
```

The lookahead uses lazy quantifiers for optimized execution time...

http://regex101.com/r/aF0eK4

Comment: This one is perfect, I forgot to use the lookahead :)

Comment: You might be better off using lazy `.*` in the lookaheads, i.e. `.*?`, otherwise they will consume the entire string each time and then backtrack. Otherwise perfect.

Comment: Good point, thank you, updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, I thought the opposite was true. [See here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/greedy-lazy-performance). It's certainly true that `[^x]*x` is less expensive than `.*?x`, but I'm not certain for this case.

Comment: @OGHaza I think that is what the linked article says (at least from my reading) - that with `.*` the engine will grab the entire string then search backwards from the end from the required character. So using a lazy qualifier has the benefit of having the engine search from the beginning. Significantly _If possible, avoid greedy quantification of the dot and other needlessly flexible tokens._

Comment: @BoristheSpider, ah good point. So in this case, are they actually equivalent? Greedy will find it in less steps if there is a matching character closer to the end of the string, non-greedy if there is one closer to the start of the string? meh all in all I've confused myself

Comment: @OGHaza You're almost right, greedy with _first_ check every character in the string to see if it matches `.`, which of course it will. It will then find that it cannot match `X` (whatever) and backtrack until it matches `.*X`. So the greedy pattern will always do more work.

Comment: I need to learn regex!

Comment: @BoristheSpider Ah, thanks for the explanation, I suddenly found myself very confused. As you rightly point out I wasn't considering the "first check every character in the string to see if it matches".

Comment: Please, @jonas, tell me how to modify this regex so that it matches string with 5 or more characters. String length should not be less than 5.

Comment: It is needed to replace the last asterisk(*) with {5,}.

Comment: It seems that your regex doesn't need to put plus in each lookahead because match needs at least one capital letter and one digit and one of special chars.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
String input = "aaaAbbbb_ccccc1";
input.matches(".*[A-Z0-9 ._,-].*");
```

Input is just an example of course.

This should work.

---

Full Java code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MainRegex {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "aaaAbbbb_ccccc1";
        System.out.println(input.matches(".*[A-Z0-9 ._,-].*"));
    }

}
```

Explanation of the pattern on Regex101: http://regex101.com/r/fZ3mK0

Comment: This validates any of the 3 conditions but only one at a time, I mean, if at least one of those conditions is true it will return true. Does it have to comply with the 3 validations at the same time? (like have at least one of each?)

Comment: It won't. Your regex will match, for example, string `1`.

Comment: @CodingDuckling, you are right. It must match at least one capital letter and one digit and one of [ -_,].

Comment: Check now, it should only match if at least one of each of the 3 conditions apply.

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi also added complete code and link to regex pattern explanation. Hope it helps!

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi please re-check my answer, I just fired up Eclipse and tested it with "laVa-1234" as you say, and returned true.

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi I improved the regex once again, please test it out.

Comment: Check it with string `1234-laVa`.

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi yes, that's what I just did and realised that, so I fixed it :)

Comment: Thanks. But this last regex won't work. Because it doesn't ensure that string contains at least one digit AND one capital letter AND [ _-,]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a better way, but my code tries to match one of 6 possible permutations ... and it works for all test cases I tried ^_^

```
String input = "laVa-1234";
String pattern= "(.*[A-Z].*[ ._,-].*[0-9].*)||(.*[A-Z].*[0-9].*[ ._,-].*)"
        + "||(.*[ ._,-].*[A-Z].*[0-9].*)||(.*[ ._,-].*[0-9].*[A-Z].*)"
        + "||(.*[0-9].*[ ._,-].*[A-Z].*)||(.*[0-9].*[A-Z].*[ ._,-].*)";
System.out.println(input.matches(pattern));
```